Can't store data in my table Is there a solution for this situation?
I can't store data on the services table and i'll still redirected on the same page
When i try dd($input) i receive input but when i click to submit data can't be stock on my service database table and i be redirected on the same craete page.
This is my store method on ServiceController :
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'tittlea' => 'required',
                'descriptiona' => 'required',
                'imagea' => 'nullable|image',
                'tittleb' => 'required',
                'descriptionb' => 'required',
                'imageb' => 'nullable|image',
                'tittlec' => 'required',
                'descriptionc' => 'required',
                'imagec' => 'nullable|image',
                'tittled' => 'required',
                'descriptiond' => 'required',
                'imaged' => 'nullable|image',
            ]);

            $input = $request->all();

            // Gestion des images

            foreach (['imagea', 'imageb', 'imagec', 'imaged'] as $imageField) {
                if ($request->hasFile($imageField)) {
                    $image = $request->file($imageField);
                    $destinationPath = 'image/';
                    $imageName = uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $image->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
                    $input[$imageField] = $imageName;
                } else {
                    unset($input[$imageField]);
                }
            }

            Service::create($input);

            return redirect('/admin/services')->with('message', 'Service added successfully');
        }`

And this is my service.create.blade.php :
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Data service')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/admin/services" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Services list</a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="{{ route('services.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <!-- Éléments pour le service A -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Title A</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tittlea" placeholder="Title A">
                    </div>
                    @error('tittlea')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Description A</label>
                        <textarea name="descriptiona" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description A"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    @error('descriptiona')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">File A</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagea">
                    </div>
                    @error('imagea')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror

                    <!-- Répéter ces éléments pour les services B, C et D -->

                    <!-- Éléments pour le service B -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Title B</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tittleb" placeholder="Title B">
                    </div>
                    @error('tittleb')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Description B</label>
                        <textarea name="descriptionb" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description B"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    @error('descriptionb')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">File B</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imageb">
                    </div>
                    @error('imageb')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror

                    <!-- Éléments pour le service C -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Title C</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tittlec" placeholder="Title C">
                    </div>
                    @error('tittlec')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Description C</label>
                        <textarea name="descriptionc" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description C"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    @error('descriptionc')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">File C</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagec">
                    </div>
                    @error('imagec')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror

                    <!-- Éléments pour le service D -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Title D</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titled" placeholder="Title D">
                    </div>
                    @error('titled')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Description D</label>
                        <textarea name="descriptiond" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Description D"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    @error('descriptiond')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">File D</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imaged">
                    </div>
                    @error('imaged')
                    <small style="color: red">{{ $message }}</small>
                    @enderror

                    <!-- Bouton de soumission -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection


I wish to have some response cause i tired to resolve this situation.

This question's title is VERY unhelpful -- the current title would be suitable for millions of Stack Overflow pages.  Please try to narrowly, uniquely describe the crux of your question using relevant keywords so that this page can be found by those who wish to find it.

@mickmackusa Thank you for alerting me that the title is indeed inappropriate

Service is your model? is there the fillable array on it?

Valid HTML cannot have multiple element id declarations with the same value.  for should have the same value as its corresponding field's id attribute.  No question title on Stack Overflow should contain: Is there a solution for this situation?  Instead of appending a, b, c, etc. on repeating form structures, use [] to have the form generate arrays to contain the values -- this will make creating and iterating the groups' data MUCH easier.

yes my model is Service '''<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Service extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'services';
protected $fillable = [
    'tittlea',
    'tittleb',
    'tittlec',
    'tittled',
    'descriptiona',
    'descriptionb',
    'descriptionc',
    'descriptiond',
    'imagea',
    'imageb',
    'imagec',
    'imaged'
];

}
'''

As mentioned, make sure that in the Model Service.php you have the protected $fillable = []; defined. You will need to add an item for each field that can be mass filled. Once this is added, the forms should save, no problems at all.
protected $fillable = [
    'titlea',
    'descriptiona',
    'imagea'
    ...
];


i have the same code on my Service Model and still have not result

Try adding an if() statement around the Service::create() function to see if it is catching anything?
